# Inteillij IDE with 2 project opened (1 project vaadin)

Tags: intellij-idea, vaadin

When I try to work with 2 projects one a springboot (my back-end) and another in vaadin (pure java without springboot or any integration) the window running the vaadin project lost connection every time that I switch to my back-end. Then I need to stop and start the vaadin project again (I never have any problem with the springboot project)
I Already try to add in my springboot application.properties the variable "server.servlet.session.cookie.name=ANOTHERSESSIONID" but withou success.

Someone already has this problem? tks

Comment: You run this on two different ports and you open both applications in your browser.  As long as you navigate inside the vaadin app, everything is fine, but once you do anything in your springboot app, your next action in the vaadin applications gives you an error, that you are disconnected? Have you verified, that your cookie-name change (which would be my first guess is the problem, if both use sessions) tracks?  E.g. in your browser dev-console.

Comment: @cfrick the springboot project I dont access at my browser he is the backend from my vaadin project (all access  REST)

Comment: So the Client times out, because the gui-server-side (dead)locks while
accessing the api-server-side? Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's the behavior when you open your Vaadin application in one browser type (e.g. Firefox) and your Springboot application in another browser type (e.g. Chromium)? Can you still reproduce this?

Comment: @S.Doe the same.. the vaadin project restarts